# Save nested objects to ManyToMany field with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

Model:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
"""Thread model for messages."""

    participants = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, verbose_name=_("Participants"))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_("Created"))
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_("Updated"))
```

I have this serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serialize User model to get data from ManyToMany field to use in Thread participants."""

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("id", "email")


class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serializer for create, get, edit, delete Thread."""

participants = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Thread
    fields = ("id", "participants", "created_at", "updated_at")
```

And views:

```
class ThreadListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
"""
Get threads list with participants details.
Creates a new thread with two participants.
"""
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    queryset = Thread.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ThreadSerializer
```

I need to create new Thread with exactly two users in "participants", how do I can?
Also, to assign new users to "participants" I need to type only "id", like code below:

```
{
"participants": [
    {"id": 1},
    {"id": 4}
    ]
}
```

Now as a result of POST code above I get this:

```
{
"id": 28,
"participants": [],
"created_at": "2022-02-16T18:22:17.524911Z",
"updated_at": "2022-02-16T18:22:17.524911Z"
}
```

Comment: `participants` is `read_only` and ignored on `POST`

Comment: Removed it: "email": ["This field is required."]. But I need to type "id" only, but email must be visible.

Comment: That's because you are using `UserSerializer` as `RelatedField`. Use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` instead. Read [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

Comment: The actual point of usage `UserSerializer` as `RelatedField` would have been to create both `User` and `Thread` on POST and displaying user in a nested json (that's why you had `read_only`) on GET.

Comment: participants = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True) as a result ->
"participants": [], I can not assign read_only=False here

Comment: Why can't you? that is the point why you are getting empty list

Comment: AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.

Comment: queryset - The queryset used for model instance lookups when validating the field input. Relationships must either set a queryset explicitly, or set read_only=True. So set `queryset=User.objects.all()`

Comment: "participants": [], that did not help

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe you want to rename your viewset from `ThreadListCreate` to `ThreadListCreateViewSet` (more readable) and maybe you can just use `ModelSerailizer` instead, since it has all that you need
2. Is better to just split your serializer (One just for create purposes)

I'll do something like

ViewSet

```py
class ThreadListCreateViewSet(ModelViewset):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    queryset = Thread.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ThreadSerializer
    create_serializer_class = CreateThreadSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            return self.create_serilaizer_class
        return self.serializer_class
```

Serializer

```py
class CreateThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    participants = UserSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = Thread.objects.create()
        for user in validated_data["participants"]:
            instance.participants.add(user)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

That's what I'll do ... hope it works for you.

Comment: TypeError: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet.

Comment: yaeh, you need to call from urls like
`ThreadListCreateViewSet .as_view({"get":"list", "post":"create"})`